# Ошибка c десериализацией файла сохранения. В чём проблема?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть два скрипта. Один из них это просто триггер, при входе в который должна добавляться единица к переменной, которая находится в файле сохранения, а во втором скрипте файл сохранения должен десериализовываться, и эта единица должна уходить дальше по программе. Но во втором скрипте unity ругается на эту строчку: "`SaveData data = (SaveData)bf.Deserialize(file);`" с ошибкой: "InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid." Любые решения?
Код триггера:

```
public void UnlockLevel()
{

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath
          + "/MySaveData.dat");
        SaveData data = new SaveData();
        data.savedLevels++;
        bf.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();
        Debug.Log("Game data saved!");
        Invoke("LoadMainMenu", 1f);
    
}
```

Код скрипта с десериализацией:

```
if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath
         + "/MySaveData.dat"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file =
              File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath
              + "/MySaveData.dat", FileMode.Open);
            SaveData data = (SaveData)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
            LevelComplete = data.savedLevels;
            Debug.Log("Game data loaded!");
        }
```

Comment: [JsonUtility.ToJson](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html) / [JsonUtility.FromJson](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html)

Comment: С этим же файлом ещё какие-то действия осуществляются?

Comment: Оба скрипта расположены в одной сборке? Вернее, меня интересует: тип `SaveData` в этих двух скриптах один и тот же?